# Google Navigation, screen doesn't rotate when in walking mode?

Tags: auto-rotation, google-maps-navigation

I'm having a problem using Google Navigation.

I select a destination, click the "walking button" and rotate my phone, yet the display remains portrait.

If I select "by car" - then it rotates as it should.

I'm using the phone mainly as a cycle GPS, and my bike mount is fixed to landscape orientation. So is there anything I can do about this?

If there is no way to "edit a config file?", if not, is there a way to force the app (using a widget) maybe to rotate?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This issue possibly has been long deprecated with the current Google Maps which has built-in navigation with various methods and also support both portrait & landscape modes.

Answer (score -1):

Did you enable screen rotation?

In the Samsung Galaxy S4, it is in the pulldown menu. It can also be found in: `System settings > My device > Display > Auto-rotate screen`.